# $L_d = \{ \phi \in L_{[-a,a]}^2$ $\vert$ $\phi(t) = -\phi(-t)$ $\forall t \in [-a,a] \}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $L_d = \{ \phi \in L_{[-a,a]}^2$ $\vert$ $\phi(t) = -\phi(-t)$ $\forall t \in [-a,a] \}$. For every $f \in L^2[-a,a]$, I want to find its projection and its distance from $L_d$.

Now, I think the fact that $f(x) = \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2} + \frac{f(x) - f(-x)}{2}$ might be relevant to the problem.

Of course, If f is indeed an odd function, then its distance from $L_d$ is actually 0 and it doesn't have a projection. But otherwise I do not know how to proceed.

I guess the projection on $L_d$ is the "odd part" of the function, but I am not sure how to prove that formally.

EDIT: My solution is the following:

Projection of f on $L_d$ = -f(-x) because I just put f(x) = -f(-x) in the expression of f that I outlined before. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orthogonal projection $P\phi$ onto $L_d$ is the unique $\psi \in L_d$ such that $(\phi -\psi)\perp L_d$. So,
$$
        P\phi = \frac{\phi(t)-\phi(-t)}{2},
$$

because $(\phi - P\phi)$ is even, which makes it orthogonal to $L_d$. So your guess is correct: The projection into the odd functions is the odd part.

Comment: Ok, so is the projection of $f(x)$ just $-f(-x)$ or is it $\frac{f(x) - f(-x)}{2}$?

Comment: The projection of $f$ onto $L_d$ must be an odd function because $L_d$ consists of odd functions. The projection of $f$ onto $L_d$ is $\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$. And, indeed, $f-\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$ is an even function, which is orthogonal to all the odd functions; so that checks out.